# Slide two divs simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have two sections in the same page, a login-section and an app-section.

The idea is onLoginSubmit() to slide out to the left the login-section and slide in from the right the app-section.

Consider this HTML:

```
<section id="login-section">

</section>
<section id="app-section" style="display: none;">

</section>
```

And the JS I am using:

```
$('#login-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
$('#app-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
```

What happens is that the login-section does slide out left but the app-section only gets visible after the transition has ended, so I get the default background when the login-section is leaving the screen.

I am using jQuery and jQuery UI.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This idea has a real problem of security. All your private content will be visible even without login. `display: none` only makes that is invisible in the rendered document, but not in the code, so all people will be able to see the content of a successful login

Comment: I am aware of this. This is just a small project I am doing to learn frontend.

Comment: Learn frontend includes security and best practices. Learn doing it wrong it's not learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var $div1 = $('#login-section'), 
    $div2 = $('#app-section'),
    currentDiv = 'div1',
    $button = $('button');

$div2.hide();
$button.text('Toggle ' + currentDiv);

$(document).on('click', 'button', function (evt) {
    $div1.toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 'slow');
    $div2.toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 'slow');
    
    currentDiv = (currentDiv === 'div1') ? 'div2' : 'div1';
    $button.text('Toggle ' + currentDiv);
});
```

```css
#login-section{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#app-section{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>some content here </p>
<div class="container">
    <div id="login-section"></div>
    <div id="app-section"></div>
</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<section id="login-section" >

</section>
<section id="app-section" style="display: none;">

</section>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#login-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
$('#app-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);

})
```

**CSS**

```
#login-section {
        background: red;
        //padding: 20px; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        left : 0;
        top : 0;
        position : absolute;
    }

    #app-section {
        background: blue;
        //padding: 20px; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        right:0;
        top : 0;
    }
```

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/25/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<section id="login-section">
hi
</section>
<section id="app-section">
there
</section>
<div id="toggle-sections">
click to toggle
</div>
```

CSS

```
#login-section {
background-color: green;
}

#app-section {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

#login-section, #app-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}

#toggle-sections {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#toggle-sections').click(function() {
  $('#login-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
  $('#app-section').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
});
```

Demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6cndzc6j/