# sliding div within another slidng div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a sliding content, the menu at the top you click and the content below slides to the next "li".

Within the last link on the main menu "replacement filters" there is another sliding content within it.

seems to brake down with a second system residing in the primary.

**js fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/30/

**Script:**

```
var isTabSelected = false;
var lastSelectedTabLeftPos;
$(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().find(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: $this.position()['left']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
    $( ".tab_item" ).mouseout(function() {
    if(isTabSelected){

    $(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: ""+lastSelectedTabLeftPos
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }else
    {
    $(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: "0"
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }
        });
$(".tab_item").click(function() {
isTabSelected = true;
var $this = $(this);
lastSelectedTabLeftPos = $this.position()['left'];
});


//Slide Content
var TabbedContent = {
    current: {i:null, obj:null},
    init: function() {
        $(".tab_item").click(function() {
                $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
    $(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
            var $this = $(this);
            TabbedContent.slideContent($this);
        });
        TabbedContent.current.i = 0;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $(".tabslider li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent: function($obj) {
        var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content"),        
            $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMaxS'),
            $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider");
        var i = $obj.index() - 1;
        var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
        $new = $lis.eq(i);
        if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
            return;
        }
        $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
        var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        $tabslider.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
        }, 400);
        TabbedContent.current.i = i;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
    }
}
TabbedContent.init();

var isTabSelected2 = false;
var lastSelectedTabLeftPos2;
$(".tab_item2").mouseover(function() {
            var $this2 = $(this);
            $this2.parent().find(".moving_bg2").stop().animate({
                top: $this2.position()['top']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
    $( ".tab_item2" ).mouseout(function() {
    if(isTabSelected2){

    $(".moving_bg2").stop().animate({
                top: ""+lastSelectedTabLeftPos2
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }else
    {
    $(".moving_bg2").stop().animate({
                top: "0"
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }
        });
$(".tab_item2").click(function() {
isTabSelected2 = true;
var $this2 = $(this);
lastSelectedTabLeftPos2 = $this2.position()['top'];
});


var TabbedContent2 = {
    current2: {i2:null, obj2:null},
    init: function() {
            $(".tab_item2").click(function() {
            $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
            $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
        var $this2 = $(this);
        TabbedContent2.slideContent2($this2);
        });
        TabbedContent2.current2.i2 = 0;
        TabbedContent2.current2.obj2 = $(".tabslider2 li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent2: function($obj2) {
        var $container2 = $obj2.closest(".tabbed_content2"),        
            $contentContainer2 = $('.slide_content2'),
            $tabslider2 = $contentContainer2.find(".tabslider2");
        var i2 = $obj2.index() - 1;
        var $lis2 = $tabslider2.find("li");
        $new2 = $lis2.eq(i2);
        if(i2 === TabbedContent2.current2.i2) {
            return;
        }
        $lis2.hide().filter($new2.add(TabbedContent2.current2.obj2)).show();
        var margin_1b = (i2 < TabbedContent2.current2.i2) ? 0 : -$new2.width();
        var margin_2b = (i2 > TabbedContent2.current2.i2) ? 0 : -$new2.width();
        $tabslider2.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1b + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2b + "px"
        }, 400);
        TabbedContent2.current2.i2 = i2;
        TabbedContent2.current2.obj2 = $new2;
    }
}
TabbedContent2.init();
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check your fiddle, it seems not working for me

Comment: Yes, the jQuerry has not been loaded in that fiddle. Load it and it will start to work for the first level elements.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915965/slide-two-divs-simultaneously

Comment: how do you load the jquery can someone update it to work?

Comment: @david, Your code is fine but you doesn't load jquery reference in jsfiddle. So just change in fiddle and add jquery. then it will work.

Comment: This is extremely hard to read, you should try to split your code up into small, descriptively named functions

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the sliding effect works on elements with the classes '.tab_item', '.tabslider' and '.tabbed_content'

Your level 2 elements DON'T have these classes. Instead their class names have "2" appended to them. FOr example, '.tab_item**2**', '.tabslider**2**' and '.tabbed_content**2**'

So you need to:
 1. Either correct the class names of Level 2 elements by removing "2" from them. BUT this will also require you to make significant changes to the TabbedContent object and its functions because now you will need to distinguish between the parents of Level 1 "tab_item" and Level 2 "tab_item"

2. Second option is to keep the class names of nested (Level 2) elements intact i.e. appended with "2" . And then copy the TabbedContent object and function, and write another function as TabbedContent2, wherein you replace ".tab_item" with ".tab_item2" and ".tabslider" with ".tabslider2" and so on, to address the level 2 children

The code snippet below uses the second approach.

```js
var isTabSelected = false;
var lastSelectedTabLeftPos;
//alert(0);
$(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().find(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: $this.position()['left']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
 
jQuery( ".tab_item" ).mouseout(function() {
if(isTabSelected){

$(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
   left: ""+lastSelectedTabLeftPos
  }, { duration: 300 });
}else
{
$(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
   left: "0"
  }, { duration: 300 });
}
});

$(".tab_item").click(function() {
isTabSelected = true;
var $this = $(this);
lastSelectedTabLeftPos = $this.position()['left'];
});

//Slide Content
var TabbedContent = {
    current: {i:null, obj:null},
    init: function() {
        $(".tab_item").click(function() {
       $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
    $(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
            var $this = $(this);
            TabbedContent.slideContent($this);
        });
        TabbedContent.current.i = 0;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $(".tabslider li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent: function($obj) {
        var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content"),        
            $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMaxS'),
         $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider");
        var i = $obj.index() - 1;
        var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
        $new = $lis.eq(i);
        if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
            return;
        }
        $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
        var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        $tabslider.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
        }, 400);
        TabbedContent.current.i = i;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
    }
};
TabbedContent.init();
var TabbedContent2 = {
    current: {i:null, obj:null},
    init: function() {
        $(".tab_item2").click(function() {
       $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color");
    $(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
            var $this = $(this);
            TabbedContent2.slideContent($this);
        });
        TabbedContent2.current.i = 0;
        TabbedContent2.current.obj = $(".tabslider2 li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent: function($obj) {
        var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content2"),        
            $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMaxS'),
         $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider2");
        var i = $obj.index() - 1;
        var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
        $new = $lis.eq(i);
        if(i === TabbedContent2.current.i) {
            return;
        }
        $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent2.current.obj)).show();
        var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent2.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent2.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        $tabslider.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
        }, 400);
        TabbedContent2.current.i = i;
        TabbedContent2.current.obj = $new;
    }
};
TabbedContent2.init();
```

```css
.tabbed_content {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
 width:70%;
 float:left;}

.tabs .moving_bg {
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.tab_item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    color: #bbb;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
 font-size: 15px;
 border-left: 1px solid #333;
 padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center; 

}
.tab_item:hover {
 color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;

}

.tab_item_color {
  color: #fff;
}

.slide_content {
 width:1100px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 26px 10px 0 5px;
}
.tabslider {
    width: 6000px;
    color: #222;
}
.tabslider ul {
 list-style:none;
 width:1100px;
}

.tabslider li /*media adjust */ {
 list-style:none;
    float: left;
    width: 1090px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}

.tabslider ul a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.tabslider ul a:hover {
    color: #222;
}
.tabslider ul li {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}


.tabbed_content2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;
}

.tabs2 {
    position: relative;
 width:20%;

}

.tabs2 .moving_bg2 {
    background-color:;
    background-image:url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.tab_item2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    color: #bbb;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center; 
}
.tab_item2:hover {
 color: #333;

}

.tab_item_color2 {
  color: #333;
}

.slide_content2 {
 width:910px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 26px 10px 0 5px;
float:left;
}
.tabslider2 {
    width: 6000px;
    color: #222;
}
.tabslider2 ul {
 list-style:none;
 width:910px;
}

.tabslider2 li /*media adjust */ {
 list-style:none;
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}

.tabslider2 ul a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.tabslider2 ul a:hover {
    color: #222;
}
.tabslider2 ul li {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}


.bodymainMax {
 width: 100%;
 background: none;
 overflow: visible;
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 0 0 0 0; 
}
.bodymainMaxS {
 width: 100%;
 background: none;
 overflow: visible;
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 0 0 0 0; 
}
.bblock1 {
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 clear:both;
}

.bblock3body {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 clear:both;
}

.bblock1 {
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 clear:both;
}

.bblock2 {
 width: 100%;
 background: #217DD1;
 clear:both;
 min-height:3px;
}

.bblock3 {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 clear:both;
}
.container {
 width: 1130px;
 margin: 0 auto;  
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bblock1">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">
 <div class='tabbed_content'>
     <div class='tabs'>
         <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
         <span class='tab_item tab_item_color'>OVERVIEW</span>
         <span class='tab_item'>THE SCIENCE</span>
         <span class='tab_item'>ORDER</span>
         <span class='tab_item'>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bblock3">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">
     <div class='slide_content'>                        
         <ul class='tabslider'>
<!--1st SLIDE -->
    <li>
     yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
     
    </li>
<!--2nd SLIDE -->
    <li>
    kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
    </li>
<!--3rd SLIDE -->
    <li>
    uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
    </li>
<!--4th SLIDE -->
    <li>
    <div class='tabbed_content2'>
     <div class='tabs'>
      <div class='moving_bg2'>&nbsp;</div>
      <span class='tab_item2 tab_item_color2'>OVERVIEW</span>
      <span class='tab_item2'>THE SCIENCE</span>
      <span class='tab_item2'>ORDER</span>
      <span class='tab_item2'>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slide_content2'>                        
     <ul class='tabslider2'>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quisUt enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi utaliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor inreprere magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum olore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant seem to get the fiddle to work at all works on my server except the scrolling on the second sliding div does not function correctly. the primary does.

Comment: I do feel that i have already done what you suggested, renaming the elements with a "2", the css js and html all have new names. but still doesnt slide correctly. frustrating that i cant get it to work at all with fiddle so you can see. https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/29/ updated

Comment: @david I can see the scrolling working on level 1 as well as level 2 elements in your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/29/

What is not working for you?

Comment: @david And did you check the Code Snippet I posted. Is it not working for you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/30/ updated, yes can see it functions, but the second slide is not coming in to view correctly. funnyly enough works better in fiddle then on my computer.

Comment: yes your fiddle works great no idea what is going wrong on my end then. in the secondary slider, its starts off blank, then when you click the menu the from top to bottom the items slide and disappear, and when you click from bottom to top they slide in correctly but it shows 2 of the li's.

Comment: just inspected yours, its doing the same as mine. starts blamk then as you go down the menu the lis are hidden as you go up they display, but it displays 2 li's.

Comment: JSfiddle seems to scroll them better when going down the menu but still starts off blank and includes 2 lis at a time

Comment: any further ideas still not fixed it :(